# Consuming ASP.Net Web API from developer client workstation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a .Net Webapi which uses Entity Framework and all is functioning correctly using the uri... //mywebserver/webappfolder/api/mycontroller?val=1&val=2&val=3

The EF and API are in the same project.

With no custom client application necessary at this point, entering this uri into my local PC browser I get the JSON or XML results as expected. So I assumed I could start writing a client to consume the WebAPI on my development box and run it on "//mydeveloperserver/..."

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#button').click(function () {
               alert('Hello. This works');
               $.get('http://mywebserver/webappfolder/api/mycontroller', function (data) {
                   $.each(data, function (n, val) {
                       $('#OutputDiv').add(n + ':Dedication ' + val.DedicationName);
                   });

               }); 
           });
       });
```

The JQuery/AJAX was not able to fill the results of the callback function even though I could see the request successfully being made and returned using Fiddler.

After digging through documentation I realized the client consuming app had to run on the **same** web server "//mywebserver/..." as the WebAPI and once the JQuery/AJAX client web app was moved to "mywebserver" the callback function populated the JSON results as expected. **The above code now works**

We have website apps on other servers and .Net Windows Forms apps that I want to use to call the WebAPI and consume that data without compromising security. How do I call the WebAPI running on my production server from my developer box web applications. Do I need to have another layer of code on the WebAPI server to allow me to consume that data from elsewhere?

Comment: you have to enable CORS support in your webapi code

Answer (score 0):

As per Ajay's comment you need to enable CORS. To do this download the following [Nuget package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/5.0.0-beta2) (N.B. this is a pre-release/beta but it is from the Microsoft product team).

For background information and to read more about how to use this package the manual is [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API).